# Why does a binary Keras CNN always predict 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to build a binary classifier using a Keras CNN.
I have about 6000 rows of input data which looks like this:

```
>> print(X_train[0]) 
[[[-1.06405307 -1.06685851 -1.05989663 -1.06273152]
  [-1.06295958 -1.06655996 -1.05969803 -1.06382503]
  [-1.06415248 -1.06735609 -1.05999593 -1.06302975]
  [-1.06295958 -1.06755513 -1.05949944 -1.06362621]
  [-1.06355603 -1.06636092 -1.05959873 -1.06173742]
  [-1.0619655  -1.06655996 -1.06039312 -1.06412326]
  [-1.06415248 -1.06725658 -1.05940014 -1.06322857]
  [-1.06345662 -1.06377347 -1.05890365 -1.06034568]
  [-1.06027557 -1.06019084 -1.05592469 -1.05537518]
  [-1.05550398 -1.06038988 -1.05225064 -1.05676692]]]
>>> print(y_train[0])
[1]
```

And then I've build a CNN by this way:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(input_shape = (10, 4),
                        nb_filter=16,
                        filter_length=4,
                        border_mode='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=8,
                        filter_length=4,
                        border_mode='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

reduce_lr    = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.9, patience=30, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=0)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          nb_epoch = 100, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=0, 
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[reduce_lr],
          shuffle=True)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

But it returns the following:

```
>> print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
[[  0 362]
 [  0 608]]
```

Why all predictions are ones? Why does the CNN perform so bad?
Here are the loss and acc charts:
[image]

Comment: It is right about 2/3 of the time; and I see input data which is close to being a constant -1.06. If this holds for all of the data, it might just be that it cannot partition the input space and optimizes on which class occurs the most, as that is its best bet (although I think your normalization call might solve that). I cannot verify that without a working example. <- That being said, a very common reason for this behaviour is a problem with the learning rate, can you try forcefully increasing the learning rate?

Comment: Cheers! I tried changing the learning rates from 0.001 to 0.1, but I get the same output. :( Any further idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It always predicts one because of the output in your network. You have a Dense layer with one neuron, with a Softmax activation. Softmax normalizes by the sum of exponential of each output. Since there is one output, the only possible output is 1.0.

For a binary classifier you can either use a sigmoid activation with the "binary_crossentropy" loss, or put two output units at the last layer, keep using softmax and change the loss to categorical_crossentropy.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm! :) Is there any difference between sigmoid + binary and softmax + categorical?

Comment: @harrison4 In theory they are the same but in practice there are differences, at least some tests I did showed softmax is superior.

Comment: Just for the records, in my test, with a slightly deeper architecture, I have:
sigmoid + binary_crossentropy:
`val_acc = 0.9422`
`val_loss = 0.16`
`val_rmse = 0.0909`

softmax + sparse_categorical_crossentropy:
`val_acc = 0.9409`
`val_loss = 0.1725`
`val_rmse = 0.68`

Seems sigmoid performs a little (not so little in rmse) better.