# Why do I keep having class "1" as the predicted class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, roc, auc

I have the following Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) in Keras, but keep having the prediction on the test images as class "1", provided that the training data is balanced. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? Thanks.

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

train_directory = '/train'
validation_directory = '/valid'
test_directory = '/test'
results_directory = '/results'
correct_classification = 0
number_of_test_images = 0
labels = []
prediction_probabilities = []

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(512,512,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])

train_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
validation_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

train_generator = train_data.flow_from_directory(train_directory,target_size=(512,512),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = validation_data.flow_from_directory(validation_directory,target_size=(512,512),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=5)

model.save('my_model.h5')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_directory):
    for file in files:
        img = cv2.imread(root + '/' + file)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(512,512),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        img = img/255.0
        if os.path.basename(root) == 'nevus':
            label = 1
        elif os.path.basename(root) == 'melanoma':
            label = 0
        labels.append(label)
        img_class = model.predict_classes(img)
        img_class_probability = model.predict(img)
        prediction_probability = img_class_probability[0]
        prediction_probabilities.append(prediction_probability)
        prediction = img_class[0]
        if prediction == label:
            correct_classification = correct_classification + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of your network is the cause of constant prediction of "1". You need to have an two output units in your final layer. A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378493/why-does-a-binary-keras-cnn-always-predict-1), and I have quoted the explanation from Matias below for convenience.

> Softmax normalizes by the sum of exponential of each output. Since there is one output, the only possible output is 1.0.
>
> For a binary classifier you can either use a sigmoid activation with the "binary_crossentropy" loss, or put two output units at the last layer, keep using softmax and change the loss to categorical_crossentropy.

Comment: The code already has sigmoid and not softmax at output layer, model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')), maybe you overlooked that.