# Keras always predicts all 0's or all 1's

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having some issues with the predict function predicting all 0's or all 1's from my model. Here is my model

```
    model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.Dense(200, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(500, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(1300, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(2000, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(1320, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(710, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(150, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ]
)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=(0.001)), metrics=[metrics])
history = model.fit(training, target, batch_size=2048, epochs=100, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2)
```

I'm very new to deep learning and trying to create models to classify and get predictions. My answer is just based on a 0 or 1 which will say if a customer is going to leave or stay as a customer in the long run. I've tested the data for null and NaN.
I've looked at a lot of posts about what this could be, and for the most part it seems that people were using the wrong activation function for a classification instead of regression problem. And the answer was that if you're using binary crossentropy, you should be using sigmoid ([Why does a binary Keras CNN always predict 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378493/why-does-a-binary-keras-cnn-always-predict-1)). I thought the output of my network would be correct seeing that I am using ReLu and SigMoid with binary crossentropy but whenever I predict, it's persistent in being all 0's or all 1's. The layers might not make too much sense, I'm still very new at this and playing around to see how layers are affecting the results of when I train and evaluate.

Here is roughly how I am using predict with the data

```
data = pd.read_csv("judge.csv", skiprows=range(0,0))
samples_to_predict = data.drop(['Surname', 'CreditScore', 'Geography', 'Gender', 'Tenure', 'NumOfProducts', 'HasCrCard', 'EstimatedSalary'], axis=1)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(samples_to_predict.values)
print(prediction)
```

I've been trying to debug this for a while and any help as to which direction to error could be coming from would be welcomed. I've tried increasing my epoch to 1000, I tried lowering my learning_rate, I believe BatchNormalization might take care of not scaling my data(I might be misunderstanding that), tried lowering my batch_size, I tried simply using 3 Dense layers being two ReLu and one Sigmoid, checked that the data I'm predicting is a numpy array and they've all so far produced the same result of predict outputting all 0's or all 1's.

Comment: What is `judge.csv`? It isn't defined anywhere in your code. Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using predict with categories of the data that I had not trained the model with. For example I have a column titled CustomerID that I dropped to train the model, but when I was predicting, I had forgotten to drop that column which made my model predict all 0's or all 1's. After fixing that issue and making sure that I am using only the categories that I trained it with, to predict, got me predictions that were not all 0's or all 1's.